# Bootstrap 75% / 25% with 4 image thumbs (how to resolve)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, row

Folks,

I'm trying to build with bootstrap. Following this basic markup:

```html
<div class="container">
    <header class="row">
        
    </header>
    <div class="row">
        <div role="main" class="col-md-8">
            
        </div>
        <aside role="complementary" class="col-md-4">
            
        </aside>
    </div>
    <footer class="row">
        
    </footer>
</div>
```

I created the following page:
http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/thumbs-promocoes-logadoTest2.php

The problem that the thumbs were 'stretched' occupying all available space. I wish it were that displayed:
http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/main-col-side-bar.png

That is, the 'main' column in a notebook or desktop occupying 75% of the screen and 'terras' column containing the sidebar should occupy 25% of the width.
Only within the column 'main' I need to be displayed 4 thumbs (as print). I've tried everything

I'm already on my knees asking for help. Does anyone know how to solve?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? `<div role="main" class="col-md-8 col-lg-4 thumb">` Edit: sorry, Chrome copied wrong thing.

Comment: Matt,
I changed as your suggestion. Did not work! I wanted to 4 thumbs and sidebar on the right after them. See as it was after its change:: http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/thumbs-promocoes-logadoTest3.php

Comment: Oh! Sorry! I misread what you wanted it to be! Let me know if Dhaarani answer worked or I can recommend a fix to get what you want.
Side Note: Make sure to undo the change you did in my comment before testing someones else.

Comment: i have done with firebug, and some modifications are made using firebug, i got as you required, just add my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before  thumbnail class just add class col-md-3 class then it will give you the exact result

```css
.thumbnail {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    min-height: 165px;
    padding: 4px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class=" col-md-3"> 
<a class="thumbnail" href="http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/detalhes-da-oferta/?idOferta=67">
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/dados_admin/arquivos/thsnc_1853y1yw.png" alt="Teste" title="Teste">
 <!--<img src="http://www.clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/dados_admin/arquivos/thsnc_1853y1yw.png" alt="Teste" title="Teste">-->
</a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this style to your website

```
.thumbnail {
   display: inline-block;
   margin-right: 20px;
   width: 22%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Try This
CSS


.thumbnail{
  border:0;
}

.thumbnail img{
  border:1px solid gray;
}

HTML

    <div class"container-fluid">
               <div class="row">

               <aside role="complementary" class="col-md-4">

               </aside>
           </div>
                                <!--<div role="main" class="col-md-8 thumb">-->
                                <div role="main" class="col-md-8 col-lg-4 thumb">
                                                                    <a class="thumbnail col-sm-3" href="http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/detalhes-da-oferta/?idOferta=67">
                                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/dados_admin/arquivos/thsnc_1853y1yw.png"
       alt="Teste" title="Teste">
                                            <!--<img src="http://www.clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/dados_admin/arquivos/thsnc_1853y1yw.png"
       alt="Teste" title="Teste">-->
                                        </a>
                                                                    <a class="thumbnail col-sm-3" href="http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/detalhes-da-oferta/?idOferta=66">
                                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/dados_admin/arquivos/thnetbabys_ern9kwfl.png"
       alt="Teste" title="Teste">
                                            <!--<img src="http://www.clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/dados_admin/arquivos/thnetbabys_ern9kwfl.png"
       alt="Teste" title="Teste">-->
                                        </a>
                                                                    <a class="thumbnail col-sm-3" href="http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/detalhes-da-oferta/?idOferta=64">
                                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/dados_admin/arquivos/thLOGO
       MARCA CCAA_2f0q5l9z.jpg" alt="Teste" title="Teste">
                                            <!--<img src="http://www.clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/dados_admin/arquivos/thLOGO
       MARCA CCAA_2f0q5l9z.jpg" alt="Teste" title="Teste">-->
                                        </a>
                                                                    <a class="thumbnail col-sm-3" href="http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/detalhes-da-oferta/?idOferta=63">
                                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/dados_admin/arquivos/thelectrolux_esvrbxh0.png"
       alt="Teste" title="Teste">
                                            <!--<img src="http://www.clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/dados_admin/arquivos/thelectrolux_esvrbxh0.png"
       alt="Teste" title="Teste">-->
                                        </a>
                                   <a class="thumbnail col-sm-3" href="http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/detalhes-da-oferta/?idOferta=67">
                                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/dados_admin/arquivos/thsnc_1853y1yw.png"
       alt="Teste" title="Teste">
                                            <!--<img src="http://www.clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/dados_admin/arquivos/thsnc_1853y1yw.png"
       alt="Teste" title="Teste">-->
                                        </a>
                                                                    <a class="thumbnail col-sm-3" href="http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/detalhes-da-oferta/?idOferta=66">
                                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/dados_admin/arquivos/thnetbabys_ern9kwfl.png"
       alt="Teste" title="Teste">
                                            <!--<img src="http://www.clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/dados_admin/arquivos/thnetbabys_ern9kwfl.png"
       alt="Teste" title="Teste">-->
                                        </a>
                                                                    <a class="thumbnail col-sm-3" href="http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/detalhes-da-oferta/?idOferta=64">
                                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/dados_admin/arquivos/thLOGO
       MARCA CCAA_2f0q5l9z.jpg" alt="Teste" title="Teste">
                                            <!--<img src="http://www.clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/dados_admin/arquivos/thLOGO
       MARCA CCAA_2f0q5l9z.jpg" alt="Teste" title="Teste">-->
                                        </a>
                                                                    <a class="thumbnail col-sm-3" href="http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/detalhes-da-oferta/?idOferta=63">
                                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/dados_admin/arquivos/thelectrolux_esvrbxh0.png"
       alt="Teste" title="Teste">
                                            <!--<img src="http://www.clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/dados_admin/arquivos/thelectrolux_esvrbxh0.png"
       alt="Teste" title="Teste">-->
                                        </a>

                                                            </div>

                                                  <!--<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 thumb">-->
                              <aside role="complementary" class="col-md-4">


       <div class="arrowlistmenu"> <h3 class="headerbar">Categorias</h3>
       <ul> <li class="arrowlistmenu"><a
       href="http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/bemvindo/?idCat=1">Academias</a></li>
       <li><a
       href="http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/bemvindo/?idCat=2">Artigos
       Esportivos</a></li> <li><a
       href="http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/bemvindo/?idCat=3">Automotivo</a></li>
       <li><a
       href="http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/bemvindo/?idCat=4">Alimentação</a></li>
       <li><a
       href="http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/bemvindo/?idCat=5">Compras</a></li>
       <li><a
       href="http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/bemvindo/?idCat=6">Beleza</a></li>
       <li><a
       href="http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/bemvindo/?idCat=7">Educação
       e Cultura</a></li> <li><a
       href="http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/bemvindo/?idCat=8">Informática</a></li>
       <li><a
       href="http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/bemvindo/?idCat=9">Lazer
       e Entretenimento</a></li> <li><a
       href="http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/bemvindo/?idCat=10">Medicina e Saúde</a></li> <li><a
       href="http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/bemvindo/?idCat=11">Móveis
       e Decoração</a></li> <li><a
       href="http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/bemvindo/?idCat=12">Serviços</a></li>
       <li><a
       href="http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/bemvindo/?idCat=13">Viagem
       e Turismo</a></li> </ul>

       </div>                       </aside>
                                    <!--</div>-->
               </div>



            </div>
```